# How to calculate the charge on a capacitor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, capacitance

[image]I have a network in which $C_1$ ($8.73 \;\rm \mu F$) and $C_2$ ($2.46 \;\rm \mu F$) are connected in parallel and $C_3$ ($7.45 \;\rm \mu F$) and $C_4$ ($2.22 \;\rm \mu F$) are connected in parallel. $C_{12}$ and $C_{34}$ are connected in series. The network is connected to a $21.9\;\rm V$ battery.

I calculated the total capacitance to be $5.187 \rm \;\mu F$. How do I find the charge on $C_1$?
I use the equation $Q=CV$ right? So I did $5.187\;\mu F$ multiplied by $21.9\;\rm V$ and got $113.6\;\rm\mu C$ but that is not the right answer?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this homework?  I presume that the "m" in 8.73 mC stands for "micro".  Is that correct?

Comment: @garyp: The question (v4) is homework-like. Whether or not it is actual homework is irrelevant, cf. the [tag wiki](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info).

Comment: Are the values you give the charge on the capacitors, or their capacitance. Unit of charge is $C$, unit of capacitance is $F$ (more likely $\mu F$ )

Comment: Including a picture of the circuit will make your question easier to understand and answer and will also allow your question to be used as a reference more easily in the future.

Comment: I've attached a photo of the network. I really appreciate everyone's help but I still don't understand how to find the charge on one capacitor.

Comment: You need to be much more careful about units. Your original version of the question had $\rm mC$ (milli-Coulomb) where your diagram indicates $\rm\mu F$ (microfarad), as well as a quantity without stated units. I've cleaned it up a bit for you, but this is still likely to be closed, see the homework tag wiki (Qmechanic linked to it above).

Comment: user140484, it's good that you're seeking out help but this isn't really a homework help site. For future questions, it would be better if you only post when you have a specific conceptual issue that is giving you trouble - don't just ask "what am I doing wrong?" or "what should I do next?" or things like that. There's more information about this in our homework policy, linked in the post notice above.

Answer (score 2):

Two capacitors in parallel have the same voltage. Two capacitors in series have the same charge. Simplify the problem to two capacitors in series (each started life as two capacitors in parallel) - what is the ratio of their voltages. Then use $Q=CV$ to figure the charge on each pair; finally distribute the charge on the elements of each pair according to the capacitance (they have the same voltage).

Between a and c you have 11.19 $\mu F$; between c and a you have 9.67. Since those two have the same charge, you can compute the voltage at c.

With the voltage at c known you can consider an individual capacitor with a known capacitance and voltage applied - so charge should be easy to calculate.

Please indicate in a comment which conceptual step you are struggling with after this attempted explanation.

Comment: Thank you! Okay so I understand that the capacities between a and c and c and b because these capacitors are in parallel so you add them. So this means that they both have the same charge? What is that charge. Do I want to use Q=CV? I have a value of 11.19 for C between a and c and 9.67 for C between c and b, so how do I calculate the voltage at c?

Comment: Consider the two "big" capacitors in series: that gives you the effective circuit capacitance and this the charge. Now you have two "big" capacitors each with that charge - that gives you the voltage at c.

Comment: Alternatively, each pair of capacitors has the same charge - now split it between the pairs according to their capacitance.

Comment: So do I add 11.19 and 9.67 together and then take each percent from 21.9 volts and that is my voltage for each?

Comment: Yes - but the larger capacitance corresponds to the smaller voltage of course since $C\cdot V$ is constant.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming for now that this is homework, I'll provide this hint:  the voltage on the 8.73 $\mu$C capacitor is not 21.9 V.   Don't forget that that voltage has to be distributed among all of the components.

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry this is for a homework problem and we've learned about parallel and series connections but I just don't know why I keep getting this one wrong. Am I supposed to divide the voltage among the capacitor? How do I do that?

Comment: Hint: what you calculated is the charge on the total *equivalent capacitor*, not the individual capacitor in question.